# How can we remove the dummy layers in the SAP BOM?

Tags: python, pandas

In the bill of materials (BOM) in SAP, there are typically dummy or fake materials are that used to bridge relationships or create BOM hierachies. One example is in the `df` below.

In this example, to produce `product1`, we need material `A` and `dummy1`.

`A` is already an actual material so we may stop here.

`dummy1` is actually a list or group of more materials (`B`, `C` and `dummy2` in this example)

`dummy2` then includes `D` and `E`.

Finally, the actual information is just `product1` -> `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`.

My sample code actually breaks the structure and fails to generate what we need.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'father': ['product1', 'product1', 'dummy1', 'dummy1', 'dummy1', 'product2', 'dummy2', 'dummy2'],
    'child': ['A', 'dummy1', 'B', 'C', 'dummy2','F', 'D', 'E']
})

#      father   child
# 0  product1       A
# 1  product1  dummy1
# 2    dummy1       B
# 3    dummy1       C
# 4    dummy1  dummy2
# 5  product2       F
# 6    dummy2       D
# 7    dummy2       E

df_desired = pd.DataFrame({
    'father': ['product1', 'product1','product1','product1','product1', 'product2'],
    'child': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
})

# Desired Data Format:
#     father child
# 0  product1     A
# 1  product1     B
# 2  product1     C
# 3  product1     D
# 4  product1     E
# 5  product2     F

dummy_list = ['dummy1', 'dummy2']

L = pd.DataFrame()

for dummy in dummy_list:
    print(f'----{dummy}----')
    the_father_list = df[df.child==dummy]
    the_children_list = df[df.father==dummy]

    print(the_father_list)
    print(the_children_list)

    updated_df = the_children_list.copy()
    updated_df['father'] =  the_father_list['father'].values[0]
    print(updated_df)

    L = pd.concat([L, updated_df], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`networkx`](https://networkx.org)'s [`weakly_connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected_components) and a directed graph:

```
import networkx as nx

# create directed graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='father', target='child', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# get roots
roots = {n for n,d in G.in_degree() if d==0}

# map each node to its root
d = {}
for g in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
    root = next(iter(g & roots), None)
    for n in g:
        d[n] = root

# filter and remap the DataFrame
out = (df[~df['child'].isin(df['father'])].assign(father=df['father'].map(d))
       .sort_values(by=['father', 'child']) # optional
      )
```

Output:

```
     father child
0  product1     A
2  product1     B
3  product1     C
6  product1     D
7  product1     E
5  product2     F
```

Graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the networkx module to solve the problem you raised, My code supports data for multiple products:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

# Create example DataFrame data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'parent': ['product1', 'product1', 'dummy1', 'dummy1', 'dummy1', 'dummy2', 'dummy2'],
    'child': ['A', 'dummy1', 'B', 'C', 'dummy2', 'D', 'E']
})

# Convert DataFrame to directed graph
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df=df,
    source='parent',
    target='child',
    create_using=nx.DiGraph
)

# Find terminal nodes and root nodes
terminal_nodes = {node for node in graph.nodes if graph.out_degree(node) == 0}
root_nodes = {node for node in graph.nodes if graph.in_degree(node) == 0}

# Generate pairs of parent-child nodes for each root and terminal node combination
relations = []
for root_node in root_nodes:
    # Find all descendants of the root node
    descendants = nx.descendants(graph, root_node)
    # Find the terminal node among the descendants
    for terminal_node in (descendants & terminal_nodes):
        # Add the parent-child relation to the list
        relations.append([root_node, terminal_node])

result = pd.DataFrame(relations, columns=['parent', 'child'])
print(result)
>>>
     parent child
0  product1     A
1  product1     E
2  product1     C
3  product1     B
4  product1     D
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation about your code?

Answer (score 0):

Since your structure is hierarchical, you can replace all items in `dummy_list` with `NaN` and then pad the values along the column axis:

```
>>> (df.replace(dummy_list, np.nan).ffill()
       .drop_duplicates(['father', 'child'], ignore_index=True))

     father child
0  product1     A
1  product1     B
2  product1     C
3  product1     D
4  product1     E
5  product2     F
```

Comment: If there are multiple products in the data,we still need to know which product group a row belong to. I guess there will still be some recursive work to be done to achieve this.

Comment: What is a *product group*? If my answer is not what you expect, can you provide a more real use case, please?

Comment: I added a 'product2' which only consumes raw material 'F'.

Comment: So, what's wrong? Did I missed something? As I said, your structure is hierarchical, so you always have a heading above any child.

Comment: Sorry. I removed the assumption that the rows are sorted in a hierarchical way that `ffill` can work.